# Powershell doesn't recognize locally installed bin NPM modules

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, npm

If I create a local NPM project intended to serve as an installable NPM CLI command on Windows, local testing does not seem to work as expected.

I have created [this git repo](https://github.com/SteffenBlake/npm-local-bin-test) to demonstrate. Check out the above repo, open a terminal up pointing at `module-b`, execute `npm i` to install `module-a`, and you can see that the `node_modules/.bin` folder has been made with a `hello-world` executable, `hello-world.cmd`, and `hello-world.ps1`.

Then just invoke `hello-world`

I expected to execute Module A's `main.js` which in turn just logs "Hello World!" to the console. Instead, Powershell errors with the following:

```
hello-world : The term 'hello-world' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Am I missing a crucial step here to make this work?

Module A `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "module-a",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "module-a",
    "main": "main.js",
    "bin": {
        "hello-world": "main.js"
    },
    "author": {
        "name": ""
    }
}
```

Module A `main.js`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log('hello world!');
```

Module B `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "module-b",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "module-b",
    "main": "main.js",
    "author": {
        "name": ""
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "module-a": "file:../module-A"
    }
}
```

Node Version: 20.0.0

NPM Version: 9.6.4

Comment: _Why_ do you expect that to work without further information? Have you added the .bin directory to your path? NPM only does that if you use `npm run[-script]` or `npx`.

Comment: Isnt that literally supposed to already be handled by `npm i`? Thats supposed to be the entire point of the .bin folder it generates

Comment: No, it's not supposed to be, and that's not the point. Not unless you install _globally_ (`npm i --location global ...`). Think about it: if every NPM-managed project on your computer put every executable from every installed package on the path simultaneously, it would be chaos. Hence as I said it's only added to the path for specific commands.

Answer (score 1):

After investigating this I realized that I was mistakenly under the impression I could simply invoke non-global command line tools from NPM directly once the packages are installed. This is incorrect and instead they can only be invoked utilizing `npm run` as a middleman.

For example I would need to add the following to to my Module B's `package.json` in order to utilize Module A's `hello-world` command:

```
"scripts" : {
    "hello-world": "hello-world"
}
```

And then invoke that via `npm run hello-world`, which produces the expected output.

I have added the branch `solution` to the example repo, which demonstrates the fix applied via diff here: https://github.com/SteffenBlake/npm-local-bin-test/compare/main...solution

Comment: Note that `npm` now comes with a `npx` helper command, which is a shortcut to `npm run`: `npx hello-world`